# Using Postdelayed to stop Http request after a specified time?

Tags: android, exception, handler

I want to stop the http request after sometime, for this i am using httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); inside a handler like this:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                 httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }
        }, 12000);
```

I am using this handler inside the try block where i am making the httprequest. But it is executing the ShutDown() Method immediately without a delay.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: make sure you are not calling the shutdown in any other places. Check if you use any any other place post that code too

Comment: you could use a timer to run  `getConnectionManager().shutdown();`

Comment: this is better than timer

Comment: @Stine i am not calling shutdown at any other place.

Comment: are you sure that exactly this code block is called... ?? please check if it is called or the connection is shutdown for other reason

Comment: The connection is working fine after removing this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why can't you use theese ?

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 12000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 12000);